# Beautiful Soup: How to scrape the data of the website if there are multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the data of the website "https://asc.gov/appraiser" using BeautifuSoup Library in Python. I want to navigate the URL as 'website->Apply. There are 344842 Results shown and I want to save all the results page by page in the data frame. There is an option for Excel download but do not want it that way. Below is the code that I have done so far. Please let me know

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://asc.gov/appraiser'
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
apply_button = soup.find('input', {'name': 'btnApply'})
apply_params = {'uid': apply_button['value']}
apply_url = url + '?' + '&'.join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in apply_params.items()])

response = requests.get(apply_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
results_table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'gridTable'})
df = pd.read_html(str(results_table))[0]
```

Comment: Does concatenating multiple dataframes into a single dataframe help? See [the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html).

Comment: No, it will not help. The problem here is unable to extract the data from the website as desired.

Comment: Why do you insist on scraping a site that gives you an explicit option to get all the data you need? You get almost 50MB of space-delimited data that can be easily converted to a single or multiple dataframes or pages, if you feel like it?

Comment: @baduker There are a few pieces of data that are not available in Excel or PDF and therefore need to do page by page.

Comment: There's *more data* in a *text* file. Have you checked this?

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @baduker there is no need to scrape the site, while using the option of downloading, but if needed anyway you have to page the results and concat the tables respective dataframes.

You could use a `while-loop` checking for the next button or a `for-loop` in combination with `range()`.

###### Example

Be aware that for demo purposes it starts with a higher page count, what could be adjusted in live use.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://asc.gov/appraiser?field_state_name_value=All&field_license_type__value=All&field_first_name__value=&field_last_name__value=&items_per_page=100&sort_bef_combine=title_ASC&submit=Apply&page=3445'


df_list = []
while True:

    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    df_list.append(pd.read_html(page.text)[0])
    if soup.select_one('[rel="next"]'):
        URL = 'https://asc.gov/appraiser'+soup.select_one('[rel="next"]').get('href')
    else:
        break

pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: The program is everlasting running. This is not an efficient answer.

Comment: There is a reason why it runs for a long time - The fact that with 20 entries in the standard per page, it comes to 17242 requests. Certainly this can be optimised, but that is not the focus of the question, it merely illustrates a procedure and can be adapted to one's own requirements.